# Polymer custom element containing table cells?

Tags: html, polymer, html-table, custom-element

I am trying to create a custom element with Polymer that contains a few table cells. I want to include it in a table row. The problem I am having is that the custom element tags break the format of the table (because the table row expects to contain table cell elements directly rather than via a sub-element).

Is there some way of doing what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported because the browser don't support it. What you can do is to not use table and instead use CSS to display you elements like table-cell,

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/display

```
display: table;
display: table-cell;
display: table-column;
display: table-column-group;
display: table-footer-group;
display: table-header-group;
display: table-row;
display: table-row-group;
```

If you want to make your custom element to just wrap a few `<td></td>` (but not all) of a `<tr>` then this might work for you

```
<dom-module is="custom-tr">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host { display: table-row; }
      .td, ::content .td { display: table-cell; }
    <div class="td">a</div>
    <div class="td">b</div>
    <content></content>
    <div class="td">e</div>
    <div class="td">f</div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

and then use it like

```
<div class="table"> <!-- `.table` needs styling from outside -->
  <some-td-wrapper>
    <div class="td">c</div>
    <div class="td">d</div>
  </some-td-wrapper>
</div>
```

Comment: Won't that suffer from the same problem as using HTML table elements directly?

Comment: No, because this is only CSS. You can style a `<div>` or `<my-custom-element>` as `table-row` for example. You can't use any of the native table elements. This is not for using a custom element within a `<table>` just for a custom element within a (for example) `<div style="{display: table;}"`.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work; it behaves the same as using the table elements. As I understand it, including a element styled as `table-cell` inside a custom element inside a `table-row` is not allowed. Does my custom element need to have a certain style applied for this to work?

Comment: You can't use any of the original table elements with this (no `table`, `tr`, `td`, `th`, `tbody`, ...). You have to use alternative tags (`<div>`) for the whole table and just format them to behave like a table (row, cell, ...).

Comment: I am trying this, but it still seems to display as if I was using the regular tags. Any idea why? `<div style="display: table;"><div style="display: table-row;"><div style="display: table-cell;">a</div><my-custom-element><div style="display: table-cell;">b</div><div style="display: table-cell;">c</div></my-custom-element></div></div>`

Comment: I think you need to wrap inline styles in `{...}` like `style="{display: table;}"`. Not sure, it's ages ago I used this myself ;-)

Comment: I don't think that's the case. It doesn't seem to help anyway.

Comment: I see where you getting at. You want the custom element to just wrap a few `<td>` of a row but not all. I don't think this is gonna work. You could make the `<my-custom-element>` the `<tr>` replacement and have all `<td>` substitutes inside your `<my-custom-element>`. What might work is that you use a `<content></content>` element inside your `<my-custom-element>` and pass a few `<td>` (substitutes) from the outside and add the others from the inside of the component.

Comment: Yep. That's a pretty clever workaround. Thanks. If you add it to your answer I'll accept it since it appears there is no proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by simply removing the `<tr>` from the equation.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]">
      <custom-component item="{{item}}"></custom-component>
    </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The custom component's template looks like this:

```
<template>
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.date}}</td>
</template>
```

And then I added styling for the custom-component in the component using it, saying:

```
custom-component {
  display: table-row;
}
```